# Do html validation without calling javascript function on submission of form.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which has a textarea:

```
<form id="hello">
  <textarea id="Testarea" required></textarea>
</form>
<button id="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit">Click me!
</button>
```

When the user submits the form, I listen to it via a jquery handler:

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    alert("blah");
});
```

However if the textarea is empty, I want an error to be thrown without calling my function. Right now, my function is called even if the textarea is empty.
https://jsfiddle.net/8dtsfqp0/

Answer (score 0):

Use a `submit` handler on the form, not a `click` handler on the button.

Here is the order of execution when you click on a submit button:

- Button's click handler is called. If it calls `event.preventDefault()`, the process stops.
- The form is submitted, which performs the following steps:

  - Validate input fields. If any validation fails, the process stops.
  - Call the form's submit handler. If it calls `event.preventDefault()`, the process stops.
  - The form data is sent to the server.

So if you want to prevent your function from being called, it has to be after the "Validate input fields" step. So change your code to:

```
$("#hello").submit(function () {
    //Throw error if textarea is empty
  alert("Her");
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8dtsfqp0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
if($('#Testarea').val().trim().length > 0)
{
return true;
}
else
{
alert("empty text box");
return false;
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
var problem_desc = document.getElementById("Testarea");
function myFunction() {
    if (problem_desc.value == '') {
        alert("blank");
        return false;
    }
    else{
    alert("working");
    }
}
</script>
```